# Main methods of functional requirements analysis and specification for a software system

Tags: requirements

I have a problem regarding the following question :

> Name three main methods of functional requirements analysis and specification for a software system.

---

Is the answer

- Feasibility Study
- Requirements Gathering & Analysis
- Requirements Specification

Please help me and Thank you in advance!

Comment: I would accept "Feasibility Study" as an answer, but the other two points  are just rephrasing the question. Although I have more than 10 years of professional experience in dealing with software requirements, it is hard for me to figure out what your teacher wants to hear. Maybe something about use cases or user stories, maybe something completely different.

Comment: Can that be something involving SRS, this problem is really confusing

Comment: could it be types of diagrams used when gathering func. requirements?

Comment: so can that be decision trees and tables?

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer :)

```
      1.Formal Specification
      2.Use Case Diagrams
      3.Data Flow Diagrams
```